# How to react event when window user enter focus into an input area?

Tags: windows, user-interface, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

I'm going to implementing an On Screen Keyboard for Window which requires the OSK app to show when an user enter an input area. For example, when a user open notepad.exe and start clicking on it, my OSK app (currently run in system tray) should be showed.

I have no idea how to catch those event (user click on notepad app) but I guess it relates to the Win32 things. Can anybody give me a hint for this ? Would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason that the On-Screen Keyboard included standard with every Windows installation isn't good enough for you?

Comment: Hi, no surprise if it is the customer reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to set a global [hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), using e.g. [SetWindowsHookEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx), in order to [monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644981%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) the [WM_SETFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646283%28VS.85%29.aspx) messages sent to all the edit controls in all the applications.

That's quite intrusive, and that won't be easy. Good luck.

Comment: Fantastic ! Seem it's what I am looking for. Will have a look at it. Thanks for your hint.